# CakePHP 3 email issue - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql, email, cakephp, xampp, cakephp-3.0

Recently I've been getting an error when I attempt to submit my form:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException
```

I've determined that it occurs due to my email, as if I remove `$email->send();`, I can submit my form successfully (however this didn't use to happen).

My email configTransport upon submitting a form is as follows:

```
$email = new Email();
    Email::configTransport('gmail', [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => false
    ]
);

$email->transport('gmail');
$email->send();
```

I've noticed that this is an issue on my own PC, but it still works fine on another host that I've deployed my system that includes this form + email sending. One thing I did do today though was a `composer update`, which updated cakephp among other things from 3.3.5 to 3.3.15, but according to Cookbook, new features for Email were added in 3.1.

I'm using XAMPP and both Apache ports 80 & 443, as well as MySQL port 3306 are open.

Below is the mySQL error log that I received when attempting to submit the form:

```
2017-03-29 22:34:51 22d0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-76.0 started; log sequence number 10351665
2017-03-29 22:34:51 2028 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-03-29 22:34:51 8912 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.10-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

- Update: Attempting to restore an older composer.lock file did not fix this.
- Update 2: Attempted changing localhost to 127.0.0.1; this did not fix the problem.
- Update 3 : Included the mySQL error log upon submitting form
- Update 4: Attempted to add in a username & password (with correct credentials) in the email's configTransport; this did not fix the issue.
- Update 5: Changing ports from 25 to 587 did not fix the issue.
- Update 6: I should add, my other email that is sent on a similar form (basically my edit form) still works fine. It is only the email sent with my add form that isn't working.

Comment: You do have a mail server running on your localhost, right? Have you looked at the logs for that? You don't mention what OS you're running on.

Comment: In the Cake debugger, Mail shows `No emails were sent during this request`. My OS is Windows 8.1 Home Premium 64bit. Where do I find the logs for my localhost mail server?

Comment: By default, your OS won't have any mail server running on it. Have you installed one? If so, documentation for that will tell you where the logs should be. If not, that would certainly be why you're having this problem.

Comment: I doubt I have. Could you point me in the right direction for this documentation? Also, in my latest update in the OP, I mentioned that one of my emails still works, in spite of this particular one having issues when it used to work before. Would you know of any possible reasons for why? The inconsistency is quite puzzling.

Comment: Are you using a different transport for sending the other email? Is that form running on the same server, or the other host that you've deployed on? Why are you calling your transport "gmail" when it's connecting to your local host? It really seems like you don't have a strong grasp of the server setup required to send out emails like this.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I messed up. My other form used smtp.gmail.com as host. I think it was because when I deployed my system to another server, I changed it to localhost so that it would use that host's email hosting services, but then I saved it to my own local version as well. But I had not changed the second form from smtp, hence the inconsistency where that one worked but localhost didn't.

Comment: So, it's working now?

Comment: Yeah I got it working again.